# Object.create vs. Object.create() vs. Object.create(null)

Tags: javascript

```
var obj1 = Object.create;
console.log(typeof obj1);
var obj2 = Object.create(null);
console.log(typeof obj2);
var obj3 = Object.create();
console.log(typeof obj3);
```

results in the following console messages:

```
function 
object 
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
```

How come that the console message for obj1 and obj3 are different? What is the difference between Object.create and Object.create()?

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documentation to learn more about **functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions). If you want to learn more about `Object.create` itself, the [MDN documentation helps here as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Comment: Thanks Felix - I'll check out those links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.create` without the `()` is just a reference to the function. **With** the `()`, it's a **call** to the function.

Calling `Object.create()` with no argument is an error, as the exception message explains. You have to pass an object, or the value `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Pointy is right!

To expand on `Object.create(null)`

All objects in JS inherit from `Object` or the Object you pass into Object.create.

So for example 
`var man = Object.create(Person.prototype)`

Here `man` will inherit from `Person` and `Person` will inherit from `Object`

However if your create an object like this: `Object.create(null)` then the result will be a object that inherits from nothing.

So passing `null` results in a object without any inheritance.